# Merging two result sets in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's suppose we have 2 results of selection: A and B:

So A is like:

```
KEY VALUE
1     v1
1     v2
```

And B is simply :

```
KEY VALUE
1    v3
```

I need to merge these sets by `KEY` to get such result:

```
A.KEY A.VALUE B.KEY B.VALUE
1        v1     1      v3
1        v2     null   null
```

The only thing comes to mind - use `full join` like:

```
select A.*, B.*
from A
full join B on B.KEY = A.KEY
```

Obviously, it leads to undesired result:

```
A.KEY A.VALUE B.KEY B.VALUE
1        v1     1      v3
1        v2     1      v3
```

Are there any options in Oracle to do what is needed?

P.S. These are just examples to point out the problem - merging smaller result set into the larger one, filling the remaining fields with `null` . The real `A` and `B` are much larger and of unknown size. We can't refer `VALUE` columns somehow - it's content is unknown too.

Comment: what are the values of Key in table A ? 1 and 1 or 1 and 2?

Comment: @Fahmi, 1 and 1, thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows and include that in the `join` condition:

```
select A.*, B.*
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by key order by key) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a full join
     (select  b.*, row_number() over (partition by key order by key) as seqnum
      from b
     ) a full join
     on b.k a.key and b.seqnum = a.seqnum;
```

Or to remove the duplicate column names used for the `join`:

```
select *
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by key order by key) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a full join
     (select  b.*, row_number() over (partition by key order by key) as seqnum
      from b
     ) a full join
     using (key, seqnum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a partial cross join and a union for the rest

```
    select A.*, B.*
    from A
    full join B on B.KEY = A.KEY
        AND a.value = 'v1' 
    union  
    select A.key, A.value, null, null
    from A
    where value = 'v2'
```

Comment: It would be great, but these are just simple examples to point out the problem. The real `A` and `B` are much larger, of unknown size, and with different and multiple value columns